# Best practice to open a tab and scroll to id inside - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons on my site and I want each one to open a tab(they all open the same one) and scroll to a specific location inside the tab.
This is what I am doing right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var paymentOffset = jQuery("#payment").offset();
    $("#paymentBtn").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("tab-label-shipping_tab").click();                  
        $('body,html').delay(800).animate({
            scrollTop:paymentOffset.top
        }, 1000);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var shippingOffset = jQuery("#shipping").offset();
    $("#shippingBtn").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("tab-label-shipping_tab").click();                  
        $('body,html').delay(800).animate({
            scrollTop:shippingOffset.top
        }, 1000);
    });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var secureOffset = jQuery("#secure").offset();
    $("#securedBtn").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("tab-label-shipping_tab").click();                  
        $('body,html').delay(800).animate({
            scrollTop:secureOffset.top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I have 3 buttons with id's: "`paymentBtn`","`shippingBtn`","`securedBtn`" and each scroll to another offset depends on the required id.

I am new to jQuery and I would like to know if this approach is correct

new code now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    let id = jQuery(this).prop('id');
    let refund = jQuery("#returns");
    let shipping = jQuery("#shipping");
    let secureInfo = jQuery("#secure");
jQuery("img.scroll").on('click',function(){
    document.getElementById("tab-label-shipping_tab").click(); 

    switch(id){
        case 'refundButton':
        scrollTo(refund);
        break;
        case 'shippingButton':
        scrollTo(shipping);
        break;
        case 'secureButton':
        scrollTo(secureInfo);
        break;
    }
});

function scrollTo(elem){
     let offset = elem.offset();
       jQuery('body, html').delay(600).animate({
      scrollTop: offset.top
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

Comment: encapsulate your code only in one $(document).ready()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimised version of your code will be a better approach of handling multiple buttons by binding them to single click event

This example is just a simple demo of scrolling down to specified div on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button.scroll").on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).prop('id');
    let payment = $("#payment");
    let shipping = $("#shipping");
    let secure = $("#secure");

    switch (id) {
      case 'paymentBtn':
        myAnimate(payment);
        break;
      case 'shippingBtn':
        myAnimate(shipping);
        break;
      case 'securedBtn':
        myAnimate(secure);
        break;
    }
  });

  function myAnimate(elem) {
    let offset = elem.offset();
    $('body, html').delay(600).animate({
      scrollTop: offset.top - 30
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
#tab {
position:fixed;
top : 0;
width:100%;
background:#fff;
left : 0;
height:30px;
}
.content {
margin-top : 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tab'>
  <button class='scroll' id='paymentBtn'>Pay</button>
  <button class='scroll' id='shippingBtn'>Ship</button>
  <button class='scroll' id='securedBtn'>Secure</button>
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <div id="payment">
    <h3>Payment</h3>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
    <p>Payemet Information.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="shipping">
    <h3>Shipping</h3>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
    <p>Shipping Information.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="secure">
    <h3>Secure</h3>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
    <p>Secure Information.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope, this demo will give you an idea to handle click events using jQuery. :) :)

Comment: plus one for the `let`s.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJorHpan for editing my code as it was missing css rules. :) :)

Comment: Thank you.
I now have a problem that the object is undefined and therefore it cannot get the offset.top property...

Comment: which?? the one in content div

Comment: just wanna check click trigger event

Comment: it's part of my website, but I tried to recreate the block and the buttons(img):
https://jsfiddle.net/2z7fkyuz/1/

Comment: just place your let id = $(this).prop('id') inside click function as in my case..

Comment: and your id='tab-label-shipping_tab' seems to be missing.. just comment it to execute further code.

Comment: it happens sometimes.. ;) ;)